# How to reset DrawerLayout navigation item icon and text colour when activity finished in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have `MainActivity.java` which contains DrawerLayout / Navigation. I used the following code in the MainActivity to launch `About.java` activity:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  int id = item.getItemId();
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

  if (id == R.id.nav_fav) {

  } else if (id == R.id.nav_themes) {

  } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
  intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  }

  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  return true;
}
@Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
  drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  } else {
  super.onBackPressed();
 }
}
```

The **About** activity launches fine and the icon/text colour of the item in the DrawerLayout/ Navigation highlights/ active but it remains highlighted/active even the **About** activity is finished by pressing back button.

`About.java` code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            break;
        default:
    }
    return true;
}
```

**`MainActivity.xml`:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**`activity_main_drawer.xml`:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_fav"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_favorite"
            android:title="@string/favorite" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_themes"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_theme"
            android:title="@string/themes" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_about"
            android:title="@string/about_us" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_rate"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_rate"
                android:title="@string/rate_us" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_more"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_more"
                android:title="@string/more_apps" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

**Graphical representation of the problem:**
[image: DrawerLayout Android Navigation]

Comment: Do you have a `checkableBehavior` attribute on the menu for the `NavigationView`?

Comment: @MikeM. Just added but didn't help. `android:checkable="true"`

Comment: Nah, you wouldn't want it. I was just seeing if maybe that was the issue.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Could you post your `MainActivity` layout, and the menu XML for the `NavigationView`?

Comment: @MikeM. I updated the question with requested code. Thanks

Comment: `<group android:checkableBehavior="single">` - That's what I was asking about in my first comment. The `checkableBehavior` attribute is what's causing that. You can just remove it.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MikeM for providing solution to the problem.

I had `<group android:checkableBehavior="single">` in the layout of menu items which caused the problem. I **removed** the code and this fixed the problem.

```
<group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_fav"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_favorite"
        android:title="@string/favorite" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_themes"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_theme"
        android:title="@string/themes" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_about"
        android:title="@string/about_us" />
</group>
```

According to android the code does the following:

> When a checkable item is selected, the system calls your respective
>   item-selected callback method (such as onOptionsItemSelected()). It is
>   here that you must set the state of the checkbox, because a checkbox
>   or radio button does not change its state automatically. You can query
>   the current state of the item (as it was before the user selected it)
>   with isChecked() and then set the checked state with setChecked().

[Android Menu Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)